# System signed application giving [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE] exception

Tags: android

When trying to install an application signed using system signature on device throws `[INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE] exception` while it is getting installed properly in emulator.
I have signed it following steps from [How can I sign my application with the system signature key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557159/how-can-i-sign-my-application-with-the-system-signature-key)

Please help me know how i can install it into device without rooting the device.

I have to publish the app and if it works only on rooted how can I go with it, please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot install apps that require system permissions without them being signed with a system signature.
2. You cannot install apps with a system signature on an unrooted device.