# Android System App Permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions, apn, airplane-mode

I'm busy trying to add some functions to an app to do things like toggle airplane mode, or change APN settings etc.  For this I need permissions like "write_secure_settings" and "write_apn_settings", which are only allowed for system apps.  Just for some background, this won't be added to the play store.  It will be used on company devices where the users don't have access to change certain settings, but we do want to allow others.

As I understand, this was changed for security reasons, and from searching here, people don't even want to discuss it, because it can't be done anymore.  But if this is the case, how is possible that people are still using this in normal user apps?  If you search the play store, there are lots of apps offering these functions.  I've downloaded a few and I can do the exact same thing that I'm not allowed to do if I write my own app.  How are they doing it then?

I'll appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: This worked for me on 4.0.4 (ICS) and 4.2.2(JB)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557159/how-can-i-sign-my-application-with-the-system-signature-key

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears that it is not possible anymore. The only ways to do this, seems to be outlined by installing your app as a "system app". Since this will be an internally used program, that should not be a problem for your company, however, the devices must be rooted.

Have a look at this guide on "Installing any app as a system app":

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/

I hope this helps you find the answer you seek on way or another.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but like I mentioned, there are current apps on the Play Store which allows you to use these functions, without having to root the device, or install it as a system app.

Comment: @WilliamRiley: The link you provided,may help in just storing the app from data/app to system/app folder.However,to really make an app a proper system app you need to sign it with the system signature(which you get from the vendor or from a custom rom),which in turn will give the app full system permissions.Check this link for more : "http://mylifewithprogramming.blogspot.in/2012/05/signing-apk-with-platform-keystore-for.html"