# Google Glass // System signature // Install APK in background

Tags: android, google-glass, android-permissions, package-managers, elevated-privileges

I want to download and install / remove APKs in background programmatically on a google glass device.

*Steps i already tried:*

- Move APK to **/system/priv-apps**
- Try to sign the APK with the system signature (I don't know if I signed it with the correct one)
- Set the android sharedUserId to "android.uid.system" -> this gave me a permission error while installing

---

Can anybody help me getting my App signed by a system signature? I really do not want to code a shell script running on each boot..

I am also getting the following error while trying to exec the

```
pm install -r APK_PATH
```

command programmatically:

```
Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Please help me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication#providing_metadata_about_your_glassware), be noted that the APK needs to meet the following criteria:

- It must be zip-aligned.
- You must not make any changes to the package name or private signing key after this (the Android package manager does not allow upgrades if either of these changes).
- It must be smaller than 50 megabytes.
- It must be compiled using the latest version of the GDK.

To sign the APK based from this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-devphone-updating/sSNXXY-yWLg/4yw4kmBTytwJ),

> On top of signing Android 1.6 for Dream with certificates generated by
>   myself, I've also managed to sign my app with the platform certificate
>   and run it with the system sharedUserId. These are the steps I took:
>
> - Build and flash to your Dream your own Android using http://source.android.com/documentation/building-for-dream. Use the
>     mkkey.sh script on
>     http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/release_keys.html to create
>     new certificates, including x509 certificates before you do 'make'.
> - In the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your application: under the `<manifest>` element, add the attribute `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`.
> - Export an unsigned version of your Android application using Eclipse: right-click on the project >> Android Tools >> Export
>     Unsigned Application Package.
> - Use `<root-of-android-source-tree>/out/host/<your-host>/framework/signapk.jar` to sign your app using `platform.x509.pem` and `platform.pk8` in `<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security`
>     generated earlier:
>
>   ```
>   java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 YourApp-unsigned.apk YourApp-signed.apk.
>   ```
> - Install the app to your device:
>
>   ```
>   adb install YourApp-signed.apk
>   ```
> - Run your app
> - Use `adb shell ps` to confirm that your app is running as system.

Check these related forums:

- [How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)
- [How can I sign my application with the system signature key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557159/how-can-i-sign-my-application-with-the-system-signature-key)

Hope this helps!