# Signing an Apk with a System certificate

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-shell

I am developing for a specific device, and I have the system certificate installed on this device. 
my task is to download another app and install it without user interaction

I've tried to sign my app with the system certificate and install it using "Su" program 
using this method [How can I sign my application with the system signature key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557159/how-can-i-sign-my-application-with-the-system-signature-key)
but it's throw exception : can not run "su" program

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "pm install -r " + fileName + "; reboot;"});
```

is this the right way to do the task? 
are there other alternatives?